# Add security rights to an extended rights guid

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Please ask if you don't understand something.  I am trying to explain it as best as I can.

The value I am trying to edit is (CN=DS-Replication-Get-Changes-All). The rightsGuid for the controlAccessRight is 1131f6ad-9c07-11d1-f79f-00c04fc2dcd2. I have used powershell to update attributes in AD, but have no clue how to update the rights in the configuration or the schema partitions. I have used the script below to update rights for admins to be able to change passwords etc... but now I need to figure out how to work with the configuration and schema partitions.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#Bring up an Active Directory command prompt so we can use this later on in the script
cd ad:
$acl = get-acl "ad:DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=net"

$group = Get-ADgroup 'AD Service Administration Tasks'

$sid = new-object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $group.SID

# The following object specific ACE is to grant Group permission to change user password on all user objects under OU

$objectguid = new-object Guid  00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529 # is the rightsGuid for the extended right User-Force-Change-Password (“Reset Password”)  class

$inheritedobjectguid = new-object Guid  bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2 # is the schemaIDGuid for the user

$identity = [System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference] $SID

$adRights = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights] "ExtendedRight"

$type = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType] "Allow"

$inheritanceType = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance] "Descendents"

$ace = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule$identity,$adRights,$type,$objectGuid,$inheritanceType,$inheritedobjectguid

$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)

Set-acl -aclobject $acl "ad:DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=net"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DS-Replication-Get-All-Changes` extended right is very easy to work with, since it doesn't apply to individual objects, but to an entire partition!

You only need to set it once, directly on the apex (or "root" object) of the partition - meaning that the `InheritanceObjectType` is totally irrelevant, since it's not to be inherited anyways.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$rootObjPath = "AD:\DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=net"
$rootObjACL = Get-Acl $rootObjPath

$group = Get-ADgroup 'AD Service Administration Tasks'
$SID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier -ArgumentList $group.SID

# The following object specific ACE is to grant Group the permission to replicate all directory changes from this partition
$objectGuid = New-Object Guid 1131f6ad-9c07-11d1-f79f-00c04fc2dcd2

$ADRight = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]"ExtendedRight"
$ACEType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]"Allow"

$ACE = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule -ArgumentList $SID,$ADRight,$ACEType,$objectGuid

$rootObjACL.AddAccessRule($ACE)

Set-Acl $rootObjPath -AclObject $rootObjACL
```

Instead of specifying the "None" `InheritanceFlags` option and an empty Inheritance guid, just leave the 2 last arguments out when you create the `ActiveDirectoryAccessRule`

Same thing applies to the `Configuration` and `Schema` partitions, just substitute the DistinguishedName of `$rootObjACL`

To find the Schema and Configuration partition DN, you can either browse the `AD:\` PSDrive (`Get-ChildItem AD:`) or you can inspect the values advertised by the [`RootDSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
$RootDSE  = [ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE"
$SchemaDN = [string]$RootDSE.schemaNamingContext
$ConfigDN = [string]$RootDSE.configurationNamingContext
```

Comment: And I need to replace the one at the bottom as well correct?  Set-Acl -AclObject $rootObjACL = Get-Acl "AD:\CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=net"

Comment: Yes, change both. Setting the ACL from the DNC on the Schema root would probably prove to be a *very* bad idea :)

Comment: updated the sample so you only need to specify the path to the root object once, to avoid any confusion

Comment: Give me your toll free number please for direct access :) ... thanks again @Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: it run without error but when I look in the security tab, the group does not show up in there in the extended attribute :(  .. I should see the group there .. correct?

Comment: I have updated the code in the top post to reflect what I am now running.

Comment: Okay, but you're kind of breaking the Q&A format. You may need to click the Advanced button on the security tab to see the new entry.

Comment: Placed the original code back in the first post.